# A program to kill long-running runaway programs

Tags: unix, system-administration

I manage Unix systems where, sometimes, programs like CGI scripts run forever, sometimes eating a lot of CPU time and wasting resources.

I want a program (typically invoked from cron) which can kill these runaways, based on the following criteria (combined with AND and OR):

- Name (given by a regexp)
- CPU time used
- elapsed time (for programs which are blocked on an I/O)

I do not really know what to type in a search engine for this sort of program. I certainly could write it myself in Python but I'm lazy and there is may be a good program already existing?

(I did not tag my question with a language name since a program in Perl or Ruby or whatever would work as well)

Answer (score 4):

Try using system-level quota enforcement instead. Most systems will allow to set per-process CPU time limit for different users.

**Examples:**

1. Linux: [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](http://www.ss64.com/bash/limits.conf.html)
2. FreeBSD: [`/etc/login.conf`](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/users-limiting.html)

CGI scripts can usually be run under their own user ID, for example using [`mod_suid`](http://freshmeat.net/projects/mod_suid/) for Apache.

Comment: In this case, it is CGI run by Apache and I hesitate to punish the httpd user because of some scripts. May be changing my Apache setup to run CGI with a different user depending on the program? Never tried that.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with mod_suid.

Answer (score 1):

This might be something more like what you were looking for:

http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/

Comment: Yes, it seems very interesting and simple to use. Currently testing it in a real Web server.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the watchdig-like programs or libraries are just trying to see whether a given process is running, so I'd say you'd better off writing your own, using the existing libraries that give out process information.